# Си.абстрактное обменное слияние.Как посчитать правильно сравнения и перестановки?

Tags: c, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием, merge

Как посчитать правильно сравнения и перестановки?
Может быть я их не правильно считаю?Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
void mergeAbstract(int* a,int lb,int split,int ub,int* count, int* swaps)
{
    int n = ub - lb + 1;
    int *temp = (int*)malloc((ub+1) * sizeof(int)); 
    int i = 0, j = n - 1, k = lb;
    int s;
    for( s = 0; s < split+1-lb; s++) temp[s] = a[lb + s];
    for(s = split+1-lb; s < n; s++) temp[s] = a[ub - (s - (split+1-lb))];

    while(i <= j)
    {
        (*count) += 2;
        if(temp[i] > temp[j])
        {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = temp[j--];
            
        }
        else 
        {
            (*swaps)++;
            a[k] = temp[i++];
            
        }
        k++;
    }
    (*count)++;
free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос что вы хотите сосчитать. При слиянии не очень ясно что такое перестановка. Что вам нужно? Если вы затрудняетесь сформулировать, приведите пример слияния и ожидаемые ответы.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy я тоже считаю, что формулировка с "перестановками" не совсем корректна.Но мне нужно оценить временную сложность алгоритма.Т.е. я потом на 100, 200 эл-тах буду смотреть эти данные, которые подсчитываю и должен буду получить график n log n( если правильно помню)
И вот..что мне нужно подсчитать, чтобы его получить...

Comment: Тогда добавьте в вопрос что вам нужно сосчитать число сравнений (вызовов оператора `<`) и число присваиваний элементов массива (в том числе и присваиваний во временные буфера).

Comment: В остальном вы считаете почти то что надо.